# Azure function is missing from portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

We deployed a function a few days ago and witnessed it show up in the portal, along with seeing logs show up in App Insight. Yesterday and today we no longer see the function in the portal or in VS Cloud Explorer. I know it's still there and running because I can see the transactions showing up in our database every 15 minutes(timer job).

Any help on what's going on and/or what caused it not to show up in the portal? And how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for support ticket

Comment: That going to cost money out of pocket?

Comment: I thought there were free options, but I'm no expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are suffering from [Runtime 2.0.11888 breaking change](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/117#issue-334263132).

> Temporary 64-bit platform option is not supported, this option worked for previous versions but actually w3wp.exe process started as 32-bit.
>
> Please switch to 32-bit in "General Settings" or you can use previous version by setting FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION=2.0.11857-alpha. Next release will have true 64-bit support.

My functions disappear like yours after I switch Platform to `64-bit`. They come back once back to `32-bit` or set `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION`(under Application settings) as `2.0.11857-alpha`.

[image]

**Update**

Begin with beta `2.0.11946` runtime, x64 support is back.

Comment: By golly, I think you're correct. Switched it back to 32-bit and back it came. Thanks!